# Using noindex with glossary in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, glossary

When using Sphinx 1.1.3, how can I create a `.. glossary::` entry that does not show up in the automatically generated index?

I tried `:noindex:` in four places:

Before and after the glossary makes the glossary disappear.

```
.. :noindex: glossary:: 

    `term`
        definition

.. glossary:: :noindex:

    `term`
        definition
```

while putting it with the term makes the term clickable and displays the `:noindex:`.

```
.. glossary:: 

    :noindex: `term`
        definition

.. glossary:: 

    `term` :noindex:
        definition
```

My term has special characters, so I'm deliberately enclosing it with backticks.

Comment: I had high hopes for my second case which should probably have put the contents further to the right, but even with that change, I still get no text appearing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, the `glossary` directive creates hooks for each of the terms that can be easily referenced from anywhere in the documentation; and that is going to end up in an index somewhere, at least internally at build time.

To work around this, you could use a standard list of definitions:

```
 term_1
   definition for term_1

 term_2
   definition for term_2
```

These definitions will then only be written locally and not appear in the main index. See [reST docs](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#definition-lists) for more detail on the syntax.

If you want to explicitly include some terms in such a list, you could use the `:index:` role.

```
 :index:`term_3`
   definition for an indexed term
```

and these terms will now appear in the index.  However, unless it is very few terms, this is a clunky way of achieving what the glossary does for you; and loses out on the ability to use the cross-referencing (using syntax `` :term:`term_1` ``).